# cypress: error during conditional testing

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying conditional testing in Cypress

```
cy.get("body").then(($body) => {
    if ($body.find("element1").length > 0,  {timeout: 10000}) {
        cy.get("element1").should("be.visible")
    } else {         
        cy.get("element2").should('be.visible').within(() => {
            //do this and that
        })
    }
});
```

The problem here is that in case it doesn't find element1, test won't move forward. I tried different approaches but none worked. Either 1st part or 2nd part works but never both. What might be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "test won't move forward"? Could you be more clear on what results you get and what results you would expect?

Comment: hi Wilt, error "expected 'element1' to be visible" and test fails. I expect it to pass because "element2" is visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is essentially correct, except that there is no timeout for that expression.

```js
cy.get("body").then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find("element1").length > 0) {
    cy.get("element1").should("be.visible")
  } else {         
    cy.get("element2").should('be.visible').within(() => {

    })
  }
})
```

`$body.find("element1")` is a jQuery expression not a Cypress command, so you cannot use a `timeout` option with it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `$body.find("element1").length > 0,  {timeout: 10000}` is a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) and will evaluate from left to right and returns the value of the last operand, so it will evaluate to true (`{timeout: 10000}` is truthy) hence you will always end up in the if condition:

```
cy.get("element1").should("be.visible")
```

*Updated my answer using @Bypass his comment.*

Comment: you were right about wrong position of timeout and it helped me to figure it out. "element1" appears on the page after few secs and since I can't wait for it inside IF condition, I had to put old but gold cy.wait() before running this part and now it works just alright. thanks <3

Comment: Actually it's not asynchronous, the expression inside the `if()` is a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) - ***evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand***.

Comment: @Bypass You are totally right, updated my answer....